# Multiline Text Using TCPDF?

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

I'm trying to generate PDFs which contain multi line text areas, non HTML. Using the Text() method puts everything on one line, using MultiCell() works, but it adds thick black lines around each 'cell' no matter what I set the border setting to. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

as per [documentation over here](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/classTCPDF.html#aa81d4b585de305c054760ec983ed3ece) you have to set `$border = 0`. So, imho if you  will write something like following, you will achieve what you desire:

```
$pdf->AddPage();
$txt = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.. aliqua.';
$pdf->MultiCell(55, 5, $txt, 0, '', 0, 1, '', '', true);
$pdf->lastPage();
$pdf->Output('example.pdf', 'I');
```

If this doesn't help then post your code so that we can help you further..